# implementing the requestlocationchange in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, location

In my application, I have google maps and  I'm currently showing my location using gps but i have a user input field where user can give their location, based on the user input my location should change to user location

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CameraUpdate to change the position

```
LatLng latLng = user's position
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)
map.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

if the user inputs an address and not the coordinates (which is very likely) you can use a geocoder to get the coordinates from the address

```
Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> address;

try {
    address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
    if (address == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Address location = address.get(0);
    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();
}
```